# clang link boost can't find 'libboost_filesystem-clangw17-s-x64-1_84.lib'

Tags: boost-filesystem

It's on windows system.

I'm try to using boost.filesystem with clang, but only build '**libboost_filesystem-clang17-mt-s-x64-1_84.lib**';
the error is LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '**libboost_filesystem-clangw17-s-x64-1_84.lib**'

What clangw17 means? how to build without -mt

I have read boost guide document, and build .lib containing -s